# dynamically invoking .NET and java web service uing DII

Tags: java, .net, web-services, dynamic, web

I have written a java program using DII to invoke java and .net web service dynamically.
Java web service is created using netbeans and .Net using visual studio 2008.
I have used org.apache.axis.client.Call and org.apache.axis.client.Service. 
In the following code ,if I include the Qname for the parameter, the invocation to .NEt service is successful.

```
 call.addParameter(**new QName("http://tempuri.org/","b"),//** b is parameter name
                         new QName("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema","int"),
                         java.lang.Integer.class,// parameter XML type QName
                         ParameterMode.IN);
```

But the above does not work in case of java web service, java takes the default namespace provides and  requires the parameters to be unqualified at addParameter() method
as below

```
call.addParameter(b,// b is parameter name,
                     new QName("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema","integer"),
                     java.lang.Integer.class,// parameter XML type QName
                     ParameterMode.IN);
```

Is there any way to change this behaviour of java web service to make it understand qualified parameters or to make .Net service to understand unqualified parameters.

Basially I m trying to call both java and .net service from a single method dynamically.

thanks and Regards
Akshaya